# How to split a string by line breaks and not lose multiple line breaks in a row?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, split, line-breaks

I have the following code that I use to take a string and break it up by line breaks:

```
var delimiters = new string[] { "\\v", "\v", "\r", "\n" };
string[] split = textWithStyle.Text.Split(
                     delimiters, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I then loop through the split array to render. So if my string is:

```
Today is Monday and the 7th
Tomorrow is Tuesday and the 8th
```

I get an array with 2 items:

```
[0] Today is Monday and the 7th
[1] Tomorrow is Tuesday and the 8th
```

The problem i just realized is that if the string has multiple line breaks in a row like:

```
Today is Monday and the 7th


Tomorrow is Tuesday and the 8th
```

if i look in a text editor, i see multiple CRLFs in a row here but my parsing code doesn't differentiate this use case from a single line break and the  above will still only create 2 elements in the array with the individual lines

How can i change my parsing code so if i have multiple line breaks in a row, it add every line breaks except the first one into the array.  So if the above string has 3 CRLFs then i would want my array to be:

```
[0] Today is Monday and the 7th
[1] empty string
[2] empty string
[3] Tomorrow is Tuesday and the 8th
```

If I simply remove the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries, then i wind up getting

```
[0] Today is Monday and the 7th
[1] empty string
[2] empty string
[3] empty string
[4] empty string
[5] Tomorrow is Tuesday and the 8th
```

which i don't want (as it has more space entries than i want)

Comment: For starters, you would need 3 line breaks to get the displayed text.

Comment: Don't remove empty entries and process them appropriately.

Comment: You should better rely on `Environment.NewLine`. Regarding what you want, it cannot be accomplished right away with `Split`, which can deliver only two possible behaviours: either ignoring all the break lines or account for all of them (what you can decide via `StringSplitOptions`). On the other hand, the target behaviour seems quite easy by complementing `Split` with a loop.

Comment: Try using a `StringReader` and `reader.ReadLine`, it will correctly handle the different line break cases.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you clarify your comment with an example

Comment: Just saw that you need to support paragraph breaks, never mind my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and remove some of the entries and just leave:

```
 var delimiters = new string[] { "\\v", "\v", "\r\n" }; 
 string[] split = textWithStyle.Text.Split( delimiters);
```

For each empty entry in your resulting array, that is a line break.

Comment: If i do that, i get a 5 entries with empty string in them.  I only want 2

Comment: Then also remove \\v \v and \r from your split options so you are only splitting on line breaks (and remove them from the string before splitting)

Comment: I have updated my question above to clarify.  I do need to support paragraph breaks as well.  Also, can you  give an example of your comment

Comment: var delimiters = new string[] { "\\v", "\v", "\r\n" };
    string[] split = textWithStyle.Text.Split(
                     delimiters);

Answer (score 0):

For a start I suggest to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of your construction. By using `("\\r", "\\n")` you get event more empty strings.

Second avoid `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. To get all the line breaks you need to specify `StringSplitOptions.None` (it seems there is no overload for a `string[]` without `StringSplitOptions` only).

And then filter it "by hand". I can't see a clever linq one-liner here.

```
        List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
        bool previousEmpty = false;
        foreach (string split in textWithStyle.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine, "\v"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split))
                previousEmpty = false;
            else if (!previousEmpty)
            {
                previousEmpty = true;
                continue;
            }               

            resultList.Add(split);
        }

        string[] split = resultList.ToArray();
```

EDIT: It's not totally clear to me if you want extra entries for \r and \n. Your example results suggests that. If so, skip the `Environment.NewLine` part and use your seperators.

But then you actually get your "unwanted" example result, because there are 4 empty entries since there are two line breaks (\r\n\r\n => 4 entries). So you may want to change to `new[]{"\v", "\r\n"}`. And what is `"\\v"` for in your question?